# How to create an objective function for scipy minimize

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

Right, apologies for the abundance of questions, but I'm new to Python and I have been struggling.

I believe I've finally created a somewhat functional code. However, I cannot seem to define the objective function properly. The rest seems to be calculating correctly (based on the values the objective gives me). This is my objective function right now:

```
def objective (x):
    global sumIp, sumIm
    if (It[i-1] - d[i] + Qt[i-LT]) >= 0:
        sumIp = sumIp + x[2]
        sumIm = sumIm + 0
    else:
        sumIp = sumIp + 0
        sumIm = sumIm - x[2]
    return h*sumIp+b*sumIm
```

x[2] is meant to be my It[i]. sumIp and sumIm should both be >= 0.

Here is the full code if someone wants to take a look: https://pastebin.com/AxC7fTVv - I believe this is the only part I'm missing to achieve what I want, but I can't figure out how to do it for the life of me, been around this for days! Any help appreciated.

Comment: I need a little more info. From my understanding, the `minimize` function calculates the perfect `x` array that minimizes some expression of `x`. What expression are you trying to minimize?

Comment: I'm trying to minimize `h*sumIp+b*sumIm` (just noticed I had a mistake in my code and was writing `h*sumIm*b*sumIm`, edited both the post and the full code), where sumIp and sumIm is based on my It[i], which in this case is meant to be my x[2]. When It[i] > 0, that value gets added to sumIp, when It[i] < 0, its symmetrical value (-It[i]) gets added to sumIm, both of which have to be positive, since this `h*sumIp+b*sumIm` expression is a cost.

Comment: If I understand correctly how the minimize function works, the objective is gonna run multiple times, right? So that's a big problem as it'll add x[2] to my sums multiple times even though I only want that to happen once for each i. I'm not sure how to stop that from happening.

Comment: yeah I was gonna say, you shouldn’t be editing values in your objective function, because it will be run an arbitrary number of times in the minmize function. If you want that logic to run once per iteration, move it out of the objective, and put it before the minimize call. Otherwise, the minimize bit looks okay to me.

Comment: If you do that and it still doesn't work, update your code on paste bin and I'll take another look

Comment: I wasn't sure how to put that before the minimize function, so instead I'm now minimizing each individual iteration, which should result in minimizing the whole thing, right? I'm adding them all up at the end of the script instead to get the sum. The values I'm getting seem better now but should be better, pretty sure `It` should be positive in more cases. In line 58, where I have x[0] (which represents my Qt[i]), I need to have Qt[i-1] but it doesn't work when I do that... This is my code atm: https://pastebin.com/cUbA6t8x Appreciate you taking the time to help me, lemme know what you think.

Answer (score 1):

## Summary

Okay, so. I'm going to summarize your problem (kind of for you, but mostly to help me :p).

You have a sequence of values you want to calculate, which all revolve around figuring out `Qt[i]`. Those are:

- `d[i]` - some list of values provided externally in a "real-world" scenario, but for your purposes are emulated with random values; most importantly, **it isn't something that has to be calculated**. (Another note: I'm assuming we can't "see into the future" and use `d[i+1]`, or anything like that.)
- `It[i]` - given by `It[i] = It[i-1] - d[i] + Qt[i-LT]` (with the `Qt` part omitted for `i < LT`); this is calculated from prior-cycle values and the `d` values, so **this can be easily calculated**
- `Ip[i]`, `Im[i]` - these are both calculated directly from `It[i]`, so again, **easy to calculate**
- `NIt[i]` - given by `NIt[j] = NIt[j-1] - d[j] + Qt[j-1]`, and **can easily be calculated** similarly to `It[i]`
- `Qt[i]` - ...?

In short: the only thing that needs to be figured out is `Qt[i]`. So if you do decide to use an optimizer like `scipy.minimize`, the **only** variable you need is `x[0]`. But if you only have one variable, chances are you don't even *need* to use an optimizer; more likely you can come up with some function/expression that gives you an optimized result directly.

## Solution

...not quite sure yet :\ sorry

Comment: The [problem description](https://python-forum.io/Thread-Inventory-Management-Optimization-problem) mentions a variable `s`, which is a "target stock". So would you not just order enough to reach your target stock? Like `Qt[i] = s[i] - It[i]`?

Comment: I made a comment on the dropbox file. What you're saying makes sense, maybe it is a simple solution like that. s (the target stock) is relative to the net stock, so it would be NI(t) that has to reach s. So for example, if my stock is 1 and the demand is 1 every day, I should have a net inventory (current stock + ordered stock) of 2, so that next day I have already 1 unit to satisfy demand).

Comment: That's what I'm thinking, anyway. That's generally how people try to order store merchandise, afaik; they don't know what the demand will look like, so they order just enough to supply any reasonable surge in demand, but not too much to hate themselves if nobody buys any.

Comment: Alright, I'll try that out when I get the chance and get back to you if I have any questions. Thanks so much for the help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Seems to make sense now, thank you so much, you're a lifesaver! :D Looks like I was overcomplicating it for no reason. This is the code I have now if you're curious: https://pastebin.com/KQsG5YnL - next steps will be to make the demand follow a normal distribution (rather than random) and add some plots so I can have a graphical view of it. If I have trouble doing that (hopefully not :p) and end up creating a question on here, is it fine if I tag you in the comments? Again, thank you for having the patience to help me with this. <3

Comment: yeah tag away! I’ll take a look at the final piece later too. But I actually may update this answer with another thought later on, that *does* involve optimization.

Comment: Alright, look forward to seeing more about that. Question, btw, I'm doing this considering the inventory management process is discrete. Would there be a way to adapt it to continuous if I wanted to change it?

Answer (score 0):

## Comment 1

*Note - I'm making changes off of the **first** pastebin copy, as linked in the question description.*

Try this: remove the `global` statement, so the `objective` function looks like

```
def objective (x):
    # [`global` removed here]
    if (It[i-1] - d[i] + Qt[i-LT]) >= 0:
        sumIp = sumIp + x[2]
        sumIm = sumIm + 0
    else:
        sumIp = sumIp + 0
        sumIm = sumIm - x[2]
    return h*sumIp+b*sumIm
```

This way, the `sumIp` and `sumIm` values for the `x[2]` at that moment are *created locally* on every `objective` call, instead of edited globally. (You may want to rename the local variables, to avoid confusion.)

Then, after `minimize` is finished, you push the changes for the final, optimal `x[2]` value, like so:

```
def test(T):
    global i
    while i < T:
        # [...]
        sol = minimize(objective, x0, constraints=cons)

        if (It[i-1] - d[i] + Qt[i-LT]) >= 0:
            sumIp = sumIp + sol.x[2]
            sumIm = sumIm + 0
        else:
            sumIp = sumIp + 0
            sumIm = sumIm - sol.x[2]
        # [...]
        i += 1
    return Qt, NIt, It
```

## Comment 2

Okay so. `x[0] == Qt[i]`, *not* `Qt[i-1]`, right? If so, then you can't swap `Qt[i-1]` and `x[0]` trivially. Also the fact that the optimizer stops doing things when you remove `x[0]` makes sense; the only thing it's allowed to change when trying to minimize your expressions are the `x` values, and it you remove them then the minimizer has less that it's allowed to do.

Regarding the general "strange[ness]", it might have something to do with the fact that the constraints use `if`-statements, which basically makes them piecewise functions. While there are minimization methods that work on *non-linear* constraints, I'm not sure if there are methods that work on *non-differentiable* constraints.

To fix that, see the changes I made in [this paste](https://pastebin.com/4ZsYG5Wn). I replaced `x[2]` with two strictly-non-negative variables, `x[2]` and `x[3]`, where the old value is now `x[2] - x[3]`. This eliminates the need for if-statements in the objective. To make the variables non-negative, I added boundary conditions to the problem with `x_bounds`. (Note that this obviates the need for a `constraint1` function, so I removed it. There's much more room for other simplifications in the code, but as it's not necessary I left everything else alone.)

So the only part that's left that I don't quite get is `constraint2`: can you explain again what it's supposed to be doing?

Comment: @Sergio Let me know if this isn't what you wanted

Comment: Thanks. I think this is basically equivalent to what I'm doing in my latest code which I pasted in my last comment (https://pastebin.com/cUbA6t8x), tested both with similar results . It's working better than what I previously had but still getting some strange values, namely my Qt (x[0]) goes berserk sometimes, which causes everything else to go berserk too. Also in line 58 (in the pastebin code), I'd like to have Qt[i-1] instead of x[0], but when I do that, x[0] stops optimizing and my Q[t] is always 0, which leads to no optimization at all, any ideas why?

Comment: Does that objective work `h*x[2] - b*x[3]`? Since it's meant to be a cost where `h` is my inventory hold cost and `b` is my backorder cost, I shouldn't get negative values, shouldn't it be a sum if `x[3]` is already >= 0? As for `constraint2`, it's meant to be defining my net inventory as `NIt[i] = NIt[i-1] - d[i-1] + Qt[i-1]` (hence why I wanted to somehow replace `x[0]` with `Qt[i-1]` here).

Comment: If a more detailed explanation of the problem would help, I've written one here: https://python-forum.io/Thread-Inventory-Management-Optimization-problem from when I tried to get help in the Python forums - obviously you don't have to read it if you don't want to, and I apologize if what I've been asking for is too much, but if you do, can you see if what I'm trying to do makes sense? (the code in there is outdated, so ignore). Oh, and I forgot to mention about `constraint2`, tried to make it so when NIt goes below s, I need to order, but there's probably a better way of doing it with optimize

Comment: Hmm... yes you're probably right about the objective, that was my mixup, I'll edit my answer to reflect that. Also, having that problem description you linked is super helpful, thanks!

Comment: Btw is there a platform where I can add comments / suggest direct edits to the code? This comment/answer chain is getting a little cluttered :\

Comment: ...wait, if `NIt[i] = NIt[i-1] - d[i-1] + Qt[i-1]`, then isn't `x[1]` just a constant value? It of course *depends* on what comes out of the optimization, but it sounds like `constraint2` isn't actually an optimization constraint, meaning it doesn't do anything to shape how `x` is optimized; it's just a consequence of the optimization result. (Does that make sense? Am I wrong?)

Comment: One other thing: you set the initial values for the optimization as `x0 = [1, NIt[0], It[0], 0]`; i.e., the variables' initial state at `i=0`. Is there any particular reason for that? Would it be closer to use the values at `i-1`, i.e. `x0 = [Qt[i-1], NIt[i-1], Ip[i-1], Im[i-1]]` instead, or no?

Comment: x[1] is also in the `constraint3` though, so does that not make a difference? As for platforms, what would you suggest? I can upload the code to github, though that's hard to communicate. Can also add you on discord/skype/whatever you use if that makes it easier to communicate.

Comment: As far as revisions, I'm just gonna use Dropbox if that's okay. Link here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6tkzsy5q974wopk/optimize_inventory.py?dl=0

Comment: also just signed up for discord (same username, CrepeGoat). I also just made some more changes to the dropbox version. Try it, lemme know how it does(n't) work ;)